# Moveable Points - Update variable without Re-referencing variable? Event Subscriptions? (C#, Unity)

Tags: c#, event-handling, pointers, unity3d, reference

So I have this helper script that I use to move points around manually while debugging:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class MovablePoints : MonoBehaviour
{
public List<Vector2> points = new List<Vector2>();

public List<int> moveablePoints = new List<int>();

[Range(.01f, 1f)] public float selectionRadius = .05f;

public bool selectionActive;

public Vector2 clickedPos;
public List<Vector2> offsets = new List<Vector2>();

private void Update()
{
    Vector2 mosPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        clickedPos = mosPos;

        for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector2 point = points[i];

            if (IsPointInRange(point, mosPos))
            {
                if (!moveablePoints.Contains(i))
                {
                    offsets.Add(point - clickedPos);
                    moveablePoints.Add(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < moveablePoints.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector2 offset = offsets[i];
            points[moveablePoints[i]] = mosPos + offset;
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        offsets.Clear();
        moveablePoints.Clear();
    }
}


[Range(.001f, .1f)] public float gizmoSize = .05f;
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    if (selectionActive)
    {
        Color selectionColor = Color.white;
        selectionColor.a = 0.65f;
        Handles.color = selectionColor;
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f && selectionRadius < 1)
            selectionRadius += .01f;
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f && selectionRadius > 0)
            selectionRadius -= .01f;

        Vector2 mosPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Handles.DrawWireDisc(mosPos, new Vector3(0, 0, 1), selectionRadius);

        for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector2 point = points[i];

            if (IsPointInRange(point, mosPos))
            {
                if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && moveablePoints.Contains(i))
                    Gizmos.color = Color.green;
                else
                    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
            }
            else
                Gizmos.color = Color.white;

            Gizmos.DrawSphere(point, gizmoSize);
        }
    }
}
bool IsPointInRange(Vector2 point, Vector2 mosPos)
{
    float dx = Mathf.Abs(point.x - mosPos.x);
    float dy = Mathf.Abs(point.y - mosPos.y);

    if (dx > selectionRadius)
        return false;
    if (dy > selectionRadius)
        return false;
    if (dx + dy <= selectionRadius)
        return true;
    if (Mathf.Pow(dx, 2) + Mathf.Pow(dy, 2) <= Mathf.Pow(selectionRadius, 2))
        return true;
    return false;
}
}
```

This an example of how I use and subscribe points to the "Moveable Points"

```
public Vector2 A = new Vector2();
public Vector2 B = new Vector2();
public Vector2 C = new Vector2();

private void Start()
{
    movablePoints.points.Add(A);
    movablePoints.points.Add(B);
    movablePoints.points.Add(C);

}

void Update()
{
    A = movablePoints.points[0];
    B = movablePoints.points[1];
    C = movablePoints.points[2];
}
```

However, if multiple scripts are adding points to the MoveablePoints Script, it gets quite hard to remember what index is where. Is there a way to have the MoveablePoints script update the values of the subscriber automatically? Perhaps through reference?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with unity but what is the problem if you make a class represent a point to collect information about each point (position, offset, color,... etc.)

```
public class Point
{
    public Vector2 Position { get; set; } = new(0, 0);
    public Vector2 Offset { get; set; } = new(0, 0);
    public Color Color { get; set; } = Color.white;
    public bool IsMoving { get; set; } = false;
}
```

now you can git ride of this three lists

```
public List<Vector2> points = new List<Vector2>();
public List<int> moveablePoints = new List<int>();
public List<Vector2> offsets = new List<Vector2>();
```

and only have single list that hold information you need

```
public List<Point> points = new();
```

### simplify code

Due to `Point` class now you can get more readable update method

```
private void Update()
{
    Vector2 mosPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        foreach(var point in points) 
        { 
            if (IsPointInRange(point.Position, mosPos))
            {
                point.IsMoving = true;
                point.Offset = point.Position - mosPos;
            }
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        foreach(var point in points)
        {
            if (point.IsMoving)
                point.Position += mosPos + point.Offset;
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        foreach (var point in points)
        {
            point.IsMoving = false;
        }
    }
}
```

for the following code

```
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    if (selectionActive)
    {
       //.. all the code 
    }
}
```

it would be cleaner if you use [Inverted "if" statement to reduce nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268132/invert-if-statement-to-reduce-nesting) (one less indentation)

```
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    if (!selectionActive) return;
    //.. all the code 
}
```

for the following pice of code

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
{
    Vector2 point = points[i];

    if (IsPointInRange(point, mosPos))
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && moveablePoints.Contains(i))
            Gizmos.color = Color.green;
        else
            Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    }
    else
        Gizmos.color = Color.white;

    Gizmos.DrawSphere(point, gizmoSize);
}
```

you can drop the nesting because they are not good for readability as following

```
foreach (var point in points)
{
    bool IsUnderSelectedArea = IsPointInRange(point.Position, mosPos);

    if (point.IsMoving)
        Gizmos.color = Color.green;
    else if (IsUnderSelectedArea)
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    else
        Gizmos.color = Color.white;

    Gizmos.DrawSphere(point. Position, gizmoSize);
}
```

### final advice

you shoud move `IsPointInRange` to Be in the `Point` class

```
public class Point
{
    public Vector2 Position { get; set; } = new(0, 0);
    public Vector2 Offset { get; set; } = new(0, 0);
    public Color Color { get; set; } = Color.white;
    public bool IsMoving { get; set; } = false;

    public bool IsInRangeOfmose(Vector2 mosPos, float radiusRange)
    {
        float dx = Mathf.Abs(Position.x - mosPos.x);
        float dy = Mathf.Abs(Position.y - mosPos.y);

        if (dx > radiusRange)
            return false;
        if (dy > radiusRange)
            return false;
        if (dx + dy <= radiusRange)
            return true;
        if (Mathf.Pow(dx, 2) + Mathf.Pow(dy, 2) <= Mathf.Pow(radiusRange, 2))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

this will lead to the following syntex

```
point.IsInRangeOfmose(mosPos, selectionRadius);
```